# Dynamic memory allocation output

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

```cpp
int main () {
    double* pvalue  = NULL; // Pointer initialized with null

    pvalue  = new double;   // Request memory for the variable

    *pvalue = 29494.99;     // Store value at allocated address

    cout << "Value of pvalue : " << *pvalue << endl;

    delete pvalue;         // free up the memory.

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 29495

Why is the output `29495`?

When I change the value to `29494.4344`, why is the output `29494.4`?

Comment: You get the exact same behavior without dynamic allocation - it's not related to where the value is stored at all

Answer (score 2):

`29494.99` is rounded to `29495.0` for `cout <<` purposes because the default number of significant digits with which `cout` prints numbers is `6` and zeros at the end are not printed by default.

You can use `std::setprecision` to change the output precision (requires `#include <iomanip>`):

```
cout << setprecision(7) << "Value of pvalue : " << *pvalue << endl;
```

prints `29494.99`.

---

`29494.4344` is rounded to `29494.4` by default and since the last digit of that is not a zero, it will be printed.